# Jersey 2 and Spring Boot - Not able to inject using @Context on Provider

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0, spring-jersey

Using Jersey 2.3 on Spring Boot 2.4.  I have 2 JAX-RS providers.  One of them implements ContainerRequestFilter(PreMatching) and another one extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider(from jackson-jaxrs-json-provider).

I am setting a property in ContainerRequestFilter onto ContainerRequestContext. Then I am trying to inject  ContainerRequestContext onto another JAX-RS Provider using @Context.  But this injection is always coming null.

If I inject same object onto a JAX-RS resource using @Context, Jersey does inject it.  Not sure what I am missing here.  Any help is greatly appretiated.

```
@PreMatching
@Provider
public class MyJaxRSContextProvider implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    Providers providers;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.setProperty("myProperty", property);
    }
}
```

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
@Produces(MediaType.WILDCARD)
public class MyJsonJaxRSProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {

    @Context
    ContainerRequestContext requestContext;

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException {
      //requestcontext is always null
      requestContext.getProperty("myProperty");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to consider:

- In some cases, if you register the provider as an *instance*, then injection may not occur. Best thing to do is to register the provider as a class or just use scanning provided by Jersey.
- Some injectables are not proxiable, which will prevent smaller scoped services to be injected into larger scoped serviced (example: request scoped object into a a singleton). In this case, you should wrap the injection in `javax.inject.Provider`

  ```
  @Inject
  private javax.inject.Provider<ContainerRequest> requestProvider;

  ...
  ContainerRequest request = requestProvider.get();
  ```